# How to evaluate Adaboost with LBP performance?

Tags: opencv

I have generated a cascade using Local Binary Patterns for object recongition. It seems that the tool to evaluate the detection rate is opencv_performance.exe but I found out that it only works with haar cascades ? Is there something wrong with my cascade ? Do I need to change the format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code your own evaluator and use the same metric that opencv_performance uses. You need to change the old function that loads the cascades and also the function that makes the detection (change to detectMultiScale),

A suggestion of another metric is Intersection over Union (IOU), that calculates the percent of overlapping of two rectangles (the groundtruth rect and the detected rect).

The pseudo-code would be:
IOU = area(intersection(rect1,rect2)) / area(union(rect1,rect2)) and compare with, for example, if it is greater than 0.5.

Take a look here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/117/performance-evaluation-for-detection/